# How do I turn malformed data into utf8?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a database full of data looking like this Î‘Î½Ï„Î¹ÎºÎ±Ï„Î±Î²Î¿Î»Î and I need to find a way to convert it all into proper, utf8 data.

Is there a way to do it? The db is MySQL and is from an oscommerce merchant v2.2 installation.

Comment: Do you know what the data should be? Has it been encryted or is it simply a different character set?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what the data should be. Its a Greek website and the data should be Greek I suppose. From what I've gathered, it's probably a wrong OR a double-encoding issue. I've dumped the database into an sql file, all the table definitinos are correct and I'm using 
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); and and mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);

Comment: Have you tried to dump the data with a greek charset (NOT UTF-8)? (Greek charset for mysql connection (SET NAMES...), too)

Comment: No, I haven't. I thought it might cause a problem as the webpage's encoding is utf8.

Comment: I meant to change the charset just for a dump into a SQL file and check if it comes out clean (with greek letters). If it would, you could re-import that file with all settings changed to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out the original encoding, I suggest you get a text editor that allows "Load As (encoding)" like [EmEditor](http://www.emeditor.com/), copy the text into a text file and open it as different encodings and see in which encoding it looks right. Then we can talk about how to convert that to UTF-8.

---

UPDATE: I just checked your dump file, copying a small portion of the weird looking text into a text file, saving as binary and reopening as UTF-8 shows up as proper Greek, have a php page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$res = mysql_query( 'SELECT BINARY first_name FROM address_book LIMIT 5' );
while( $r = mysql_fetch_row( $res ) ) {
    echo $r[0].'<br />';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

see what you get.

Comment: I've just done it, it doesn't look right under any encoding. I've uploaded the sql dump file in case anyone want's to have a look at it: http://www.mediafire.com/?9d52gm9pa3t5ers

Comment: depends on the editor, in EmEditor it is Binary (Ascii view) which treats the text as a stream of bytes (doesn't do any coversion on it).

Comment: I followed you instructions using EmEditor, saved the first few lines as binary and reopened the sql file, converted it into utf8 and still looks exaclty like the initial file. Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: @bikey77 I'm pretty sure you have proper UTF-8 in your db but it's being converted to binary and back to utf-8 somewhere in the way, if you do `SELECT BINARY col_name` like I mentioned in my update you should get proper Greek in your browser.

Comment: @bikey77 Well I don't know what you are doing wrong but this is what I got from a portion of the text: Χαράλαμπος

Comment: Ok, here's another problem: Ι'm entering data and it shows like this &#915;&#923;&#933;&#934;&#913;&#916;&#913;

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd try to identify what the character set of the data is. To do this:

- use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to find out the collation of the MySQL table that has the data in
- set your client to use the same collation (this ensures that no translation is peformed)
- export the table with `mysqldump` to a file on the server

Now you've got a copy of the data from the table that's un-altered and byte for byte the same as what's stored in the database. Using your favourite text editor try to switch character set encodings and work out what character set the data is stored in. When you eventually set the correct character set in your browser the text will render correctly.

Likely candidates for the encoding will be `ISO-8859-7` or `UTF-8`.

Once you've identified the correct encoding you should be able to modify the charset encoding in the mysqldump file and then load this data correctly into a new table.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE XXXXX shows that the tables are utf8. What should I do now?